# Find $X/1430$ when $X=(^{10}C_1)^2+2(^{10}C_2)^2+3(^{10}C_3)^2+ ...+10(^{10}C_{10})^2$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $X=(^{10}C_1)^2+2(^{10}C_2)^2+3(^{10}C_3)^2+ ...+10(^{10}C_{10})^2$, then what's the value of $X\over1430$?

I don't even know where to begin on this question. All solutions I've seen on various sites start by writing this as a summation and simplifying, and eventually bring it into this form:

$$=10\sum_{r=1}^{10}C^{10}_{r}*^{9}C_{r-1}$$. Until this point, I understand, but after this, I dont understand at all.

Comment: At this point, you should use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Comment: You used both $C^{10}_r$ and $~^9C_{r-1}$ notations in the same expression... You should be more consistent.  That being said, $\binom{n}{r}$ is more common notation that is cleaner and avoids frustrations of the notation you use, particular in that some authors flip the positions of $n$ and $r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the identity:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&1+C_1^{19}x+\dots+C_9^{19}x^9+C_{10}^{19}x^{10}+\dots +x^{19}
\\
&\qquad=(1+x)^{19}
\\
&\qquad=(1+x)^{10}(1+x)^{9}
\\
&\qquad=
(C_0^{10} + C_1^{10}x+ C_2^{10}x^2+\dots + C_{10}^{10}x^{10})
\cdot
(C_0^9 + C_1^9x+ C_2^9x^2+\dots + C_9^9x^9)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let us isolate in the start and in the end expression the term in degree ten.
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_{10}^{19}
&=
C_{10}^{10}\cdot C_0^9 +
C_9^{10}\cdot C_1^9 +
C_8^{10}\cdot C_2^9 +
C_7^{10}\cdot C_3^9 +
C_6^{10}\cdot C_4^9 
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
C_5^{10}\cdot C_5^9 +
C_4^{10}\cdot C_6^9 +
C_3^{10}\cdot C_7^9 +
C_2^{10}\cdot C_8^9 +
C_1^{10}\cdot C_9^9
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last sum also appears in the question. So we have to compute ten times of it to get $X$, then finally:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac X{1430}
&=\frac{10\cdot C_{10}^{19}}{1430}
=\frac1{143}\cdot C_{10}^{19}
=
\frac1{11\cdot 13}
\cdot
\frac
{11\cdot 12\cdot 13\cdot 14\cdot 15\cdot 16\cdot 17\cdot 18\cdot 19}
{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9}
\\
&=
\frac
{12\cdot 14\cdot 15\cdot 16\cdot 17\cdot 18\cdot 19}
{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9}
=
\frac
{14\cdot 16\cdot 17\cdot 18\cdot 19}
{ 4\cdot 7\cdot 8\cdot 9}
=
\frac
{16\cdot 17\cdot 19}
{ 8}
\\
&=2\cdot 17\cdot 19=646\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Computer check:

```
sage: X = sum([ r*binomial(10, r)^2 for r in [0..10] ])
sage: X / 1430
646
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation using the binomial theorem and a bit of algebra. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{r}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^r\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{X}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{r=1}^{10}r\binom{10}{r}^2}=10\sum_{r=1}\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{r-1}\tag{2}\\
> &=10\sum_{r=1}^{10}\binom{10}{r}\binom{9}{10-r}\tag{3}\\
> &=10\sum_{r=1}^{10}\binom{10}{r}[x^{10-r}](1+x)^9\tag{4}\\
> &=10[x^{10}](1+x)^9\sum_{r=1}^{10}\binom{10}{r}x^r\tag{5}\\
> &=10[x^{10}](1+x)^9\left((1+x)^{10}-1\right)\tag{6}\\
> &=10[x^{10}](1+x)^{19}\tag{7}\\
> &\;\;\color{blue}{=10\binom{19}{10}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
> We finally calculate $\color{blue}{X}=\frac{10}{1\,430}\binom{19}{10}\color{blue}{=646}$.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{r}{k}=\frac{r}{k}\binom{r-1}{k-1}$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{r}{k}=\binom{r}{r-k}$.
- In (4) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (5) we apply the rule $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$ and factor out terms which do not depend on the summation index $r$.
- In (6) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (7) we observe $[x^{10}](1+x)^{9}=0$.
- in (8) we select the coefficient of $x^{10}$.

Comment: this was nice $+1$ ! and deserve to be the accepted answer

Comment: @TheDateTree: Thanks for your nice comment and the credit. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all remember that when $n \geq k\geq0:$ $$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$$

Now, using Vandermonde identity realize that : $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}$$

Moreover , $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{n-k}^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(n-k)\binom{n}{k}^2$$

By summing these two foregoing identity :

$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2$$

The right hand side says that use Vandermodes' identity , so : $$n\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2=n\binom{2n}{n}$$ Then ,$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=n\binom{2n}{n}$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}k\binom{n}{k}^2=\bigg(\frac{n}{2}\bigg)\binom{2n}{n}$$

In this question ,  we have $n=10$ ,so $$X=5\binom{20}{10}=5\times184,756=923,780$$
$$\frac{X}{1430}=\frac{923,780}{1430}=646$$